# I try to import a huge csv file into my wpf Application but i get an array error System.IndexOutOfRangeException after importing

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

So here is the code it starts with the get and sets from each header
The csv has 16 Column Elemetns but 100+ Row Elements.

```
public class Cloths
        {
            public string Hauptartikelnr { get; set; }
            public string Artikelname { get; set; }
            public string Hersteller { get; set; }
            public string Beschreibung { get; set; }
            public string Materialangaben { get; set; }
            public Gender Geschlecht { get; set; }
            public string Produktart { get; set; }
            public string Aermel { get; set; }
            public string Bein { get; set; }
            public string Kragen { get; set; }
            public string Herstellung { get; set; }
            public string Taschenart { get; set; }
            public string Grammatur { get; set; }
            public string Material { get; set; }
            public string Ursprungsland { get; set; }
            public string Bildname { get; set; }
        }
public enum Gender
        {
            Herren,
            Damen,
            Kind
        }
```

And here is the were the Error starts, so after importing a csv file i get the error System.IndexOutOfRangeException and all arrays are markt.

```
public static class CSVTable
        {
            public static List<Cloths> ReadFile(string filepath)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

                var data = from l in lines.Skip(1)
                           let split = l.Split(';')
                           select new Cloths
                           {
                               Hauptartikelnr = split[0],
                               Artikelname = split[1],
                               Hersteller = split[2],
                               Beschreibung = split[3],
                               Materialangaben = split[4],
                               Geschlecht = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), split[5]),
                               Produktart = split[6],
                               Aermel = split[7],
                               Bein = split[8],
                               Kragen = split[9],
                               Herstellung = split[10],
                               Taschenart = split[11],
                               Grammatur = split[12],
                               Material = split[13],
                               Ursprungsland = split[14],
                               Bildname = split[15]


                           };

                return data.ToList();
            }
        }
```

If u need and ohter informations just ask me I rly wanna solve this

Comment: the line that you are splitting on ; does not always contains 15 elements.

Comment: Are you sure every line in the CSV file has all of the fields? Your error would suggest not. There are a lot of CSV libraries that would help a lot.

Comment: _and all arrays are markt._ It obviously that English isn't your first language, but I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: As @pix suggests, the obvious explanation is that you have lines with less that 15 elements. Check you file. Pay particular attention to any blank lines at the end of the file. You should add checks to you code for the length of `split` and (potentially) skip any that are `<15`.

Comment: If split has 15 columns, the last index should be split[14], not split[15]. You are basically trying to get 16 different values out of split (0-15 including). The last one results in the IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: The csv has 16 Column Elemetns but 100+ Row Elements. @ValentinSky sry was a misstype there are 16 columns*

Comment: I agree with the above comments that you have an empty row or one with not all 16 columns. Make a copy of your original csv file and only keep the first two rows. If that works, then you know your code is working. Then set some breakpoints and error catching and start debugging until you find the row in your csv that is throwing the error.

Comment: comment out the entire select section and exchange it with `select split.Length` then after the query put this code: `Console.WriteLine(data.Any(x => x < 16));` then you look into your output window in visual studio and you will see whether the people here are correct with their assumptions

Comment: a) 100 rows is not huge but tiny. b) __always test__ the length of the resulting array after a split!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you what the exact error is, but as [Jack Hughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42109/jack-hughes) already said, it might be possible that not all your rows do really have 16 columns.

You seem to struggle finding the spot, as multiple lines are marked red when the error is thrown. You could therefore split your logic to set `data` like the following:

```
var data = new List<Cloths>();
foreach (var line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    var split = line.Split(";");
    if(split.Length != 16)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var cloths = new Cloths();
    cloths.Hauptartikelnr = split[0];
    cloths.Artikelname = split[1];
    cloths.Hersteller = split[2];
    cloths.Beschreibung = split[3];
    cloths.Materialangaben = split[4];
    cloths.Geschlecht = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), split[5]);
    cloths.Produktart = split[6];
    cloths.Aermel = split[7];
    cloths.Bein = split[8];
    cloths.Kragen = split[9];
    cloths.Herstellung = split[10];
    cloths.Taschenart = split[11];
    cloths.Grammatur = split[12];
    cloths.Material = split[13];
    cloths.Ursprungsland = split[14];
    cloths.Bildname = split[15];

    data.Add(cloths);
}
```

Comment: I would add a check to make sure that split is 16 elements long. If it is not then you should either skip that line or throw an exception to stop the app. You could also set a breakpoint there to find the exact line that is causing the problem.